# JavaScript to PHP timestamp failing, adds about a month and a half to the time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datetime, timestamp

Ok, Im trying to convert a javascript timestamp to a php equivalent, I have surfed the posts here on stack for a decent answer as well as various other sites so this question comes as a last ditch effort despite knowing Im likely to get down votes, and someone telling me nothing more than this is a dupe question from somewhere else. So despite that..

This is my failure of an attempt thus far. Please Note I am using jQuery, with noConflict hence the `j` rather than the `$`

```
var yr = j('#time_year :selected').val();//year
var mn = j('#time_month :selected').val();//month
var dy = j('#time_day :selected').val();//day
var hr = j('#time_hour :selected').val();//hour
var min = j('#time_minute :selected').val();//minute
var sc = j('#time_second :selected').val();//second

if(j('#time_ampm :selected').val() == 12 && j('#time_hour :selected').val() < 12){hr = j('#time_hour :selected').val()+12;}
if(j('#time_ampm :selected').val() == 0 && j('#time_hour :selected').val() == 12){hr = 0;}

var theDate = new Date(yr, mn, dy, hr, min, sc).getTime();
setTimeStamps(theDate);
j('#timestamp_now_js').html(" "+theTime);
j('#timestamp_now_php').html(" "+Math.round(theTime / 1000));
```

The select values at the top are based off of [Mozilla.org Date reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date) using 0-nn as they describe. Where as the am/pm if-else is essentially meant to add 12 hours to the time selected as the time displayed on the site is 12-hour format. Javascript uses 24-hour. Its also there in the event that if am is picked and the use 12 it will convert 12 to 0 to match the 24-hour formatting concept.

Currently what appears to be happening is that despite it seeming to work, when I run the timestamp given through a php `date()` function it shows a date thats about a month 2 weeks and a few days a head of what I am testing off of, which is the equivalent of now

I would create a jsFiddle of the whole thing html included, but I use php through out to generate my select boxes. So with that if you want to see what I have "live" then go to http://7pz.net/timestamps.php as thats where I am testing the concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in Javascript's `Date` objects the month range is 0-11, not 1-12. That's for the "month" part. Try this:

```
var mn = j('#time_month :selected').val() - 1; //month
```

Or better, generate the `<option>`s with values ranging from 0 to 11.

Plus, this statement:

```
hr = j('#time_hour :selected').val()+12;
```

Remember that `j('#time_hour :selected').val()` is a *string*, not a number, so you have to convert it before adding 12, or else you'd get something like `"0412"`. You're creating a date with the hour count set to 412, i.e. 17 days and 4 hours. And 17 days are addes to the day count.

Fix it like this:

```
hr = +j('#time_hour :selected').val() + 12;
```

I used the [plus unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29).

(P.S.: there's a lot of room to improve your code, starting with readability and jQuery object caching. Take some time improving your Javascript coding skills before getting used to some bad practices.)

Comment: Could you elaborate on room to improve? Cause despite not showing it through this example, and maybe a handful of others I have done in time here on stack. I do practice caching, and tend to have a much more readable code base. But you wouldn't know that, and just assume. If you knew me, then you'd realize this is just me playing in my own sandbox, and with that, since its not a collaborative effort I tend not to care as all that generally matters is that I can read it in this case. Sure its my fault for not cleaning it up prior to posting but don't judge solely on that.

Comment: Anyway nice call on the sting vs number piece, I completely skipped over that. First time really playing with dates in Javascript as I usually pass things around to a server side method of handling them.

Comment: @chris I thought you were a Javascript beginner because: 1) the `:selected` part isn't needed to get the `<select>` value; 2) knowing that months in `Date` start at 0 is quite basic knowledge; 3) using multiple jQuery calls with the same selectors; 4) converting to string is unnecessary for `html()` (or, if you just wanted to add a space, that isn' rendered anyway); 5) the problem with adding 12 is a pretty basic Javascript caveat too (in PHP the plus is solely a numeric operator). Forgive me if you're actually a Javascript guru, but please post more readable code for other users' sake.